# Update/Insert into a joined view with Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE one {
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  thing varchar(255)
}

CREATE TABLE two {
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  thing2 varchar(255),
  one_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES one(id)
}
```

I'm creating a view on these two tables using the following:

```
CREATE VIEW view_table 
AS SELECT one.id, thing, thing2 FROM one, two 
WHERE two.one_id = one.id;
```

I have a model similar to this:

```
<?php class Blah { protected $table = 'view_table'; }
```

---

The desired functionality I hoped to achieve is that when creating a new instance of the `Blah` object and saving it (`Blah::create($data)`) I would see properly related rows in both my tables, **one** and **two**. What I'm getting is a new row in **one**, while **two** is completely empty still. What am I missing to achieve the desired functionality?

Edit:
After resolving a slight error I made, it seems that I've made a mistake, it seems that I simply cannot insert into join-views, only udpate. Is there an elegant solution to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, you might use an "instead of" trigger on the view. MySQL doesn't support "instead of" triggers. It doesn't support triggers on views, either.

Using a framework that includes an ORM is different. You *probably* want to use [two models and the `hasMany()` method](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many).